# Debuguear libreria en ReactJS desde aplicación en ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack, es6

Estimados,

Estoy implementando una aplicación web en ReactJS para la cual utilizo una librería OpenSource en ReactJS que me brinda los componentes para armar la aplicación. (https://github.com/boundlessgeo/sdk).

Para poder personalizar uno de los componentes que me brinda la librería, necesito debuguear la aplicación para ver cómo se comporta dicho componente. Cuando hago el debugging mediante el VSCode, me lleva al código transpilado de la librería. 
Quisiera bajar el código de la librería en ReactJS para poder debuguear en conjunto con el código de mi aplicación.
Les cuento que soy novato en ReactJS, npm, babel, webpack, etc.

Cómo puedo hacer esto? Alguien me puede mencionar alguna herramienta o un ejemplo?

Slds

Comment: Puedes utilizar [React Developer Tools](https://github.com/facebook/react-devtools) que tiene extensiones para Chrome y Firefox, o como [app independiente](https://github.com/facebook/react-devtools/tree/master/packages/react-devtools)

Comment: La instalé pero lo que puedo hacer es inspeccionar los elementos. Lo que quiero es ir siguiendo la ejecución del código pudiendo insertar breakpoints pero visualizando en ES6. He visto que se puede hacer con webpack. Puede ser?

Comment: Puedes utilizar [Nuclide](https://nuclide.io/), es bastante completo para desarollar con ES6 y React, [aquí](https://nuclide.io/docs/features/debugger/#breakpoints) te dejo la parte de breakpoints